# How to make a setter and getter test and make the result outprint in the main?

Tags: java

```
public TripleString() {
    string1 = DEFAULT_STRING;
    string2 = DEFAULT_STRING;
    string3 = DEFAULT_STRING;
}
public TripleString(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
   string1 = DEFAULT_STRING;
   string2 = DEFAULT_STRING;
   string3 = DEFAULT_STRING;
   this.setString1(str1);
   this.setString2(str2);
   this.setString3(str3);
}
public boolean setString1(String str1) {
    if (str1.length() < MIN_LEN || str1.length() > MAX_LEN) {
        return false;
    } else {
        string1 = str1;
        return true;
    }
}
public String getString1() {
    return string1;
}
public String toString(){
    return "string1 = "+string1+"; string2 = "+string2+"; string3 = "+string3 + "\n";
}
```

The question is like there are two classes,and how can I get the boolean setString1 which is the setter from the subclass and output it directly instead of making an additional method like do if and using String.length()? Should I make the call like "triple1.setString1"? The original question is     "Do two or more explicit mutator tests. For each, call a mutator in an if/else statement which prints one message if the call is successful and a different message if the call fails. "    Thank you so much for viewing and helping.

Comment: I don't understand your problem statement.

Comment: Because I'm confusing about the problem too. If the setter passed then the string will be set to String1 so the boolean itself is not used as true or false. But the question want us to print one message to show whether the test passed or not. I'm confusing about how to achieve that.

Comment: Can you tell us, in clear terms, exactly what the `setString1` method is supposed to be doing?

Comment: setString1 should set a value of a instance field to a given value which is string1. I think this is what it should do if I didn't make that wrong.

Comment: emmmm seems I find a way out to proof the setter is working. Thank you any way dude. Sorry for wasting you so much time.